# How to force enable/disable of controls in aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have a simple windows form app which I have to migrate to run on a webpage, so I'm trying with aspx(c#).

I have two radio buttons, but at time only one of them should be checked. I implemented the very same code from the original app, but it's not working:

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton2.Checked = false;
        }
    }
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            RadioButton1.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

So why these changes not being applied on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `GroupName` Property of `RadioButton` Control.

if you set the same `GroupName` for set of `RadioButtons` you don't need to write the Code Behid which you have written in the above Post/Question, as only one radio button can be selected from the group.

but if you want to invoke some action like Disabling `TextBox` on Particular Radio Button click event you can use following sample code.

**Example:** in this example i'm taking 3 Radio Buttons all set to Same `GroupName`, hence only one `RadioButton` canbe selected at a time.

when user selects/checks a RadioButton1 i'm Disabling the TextBox1.

**Note :** Please Make sure that your `RadioButton` `AutoPostBack` Property set to `True` otherwise events on `RadioButton` won't be fired.

**Design Code:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="DisableTextBox" GroupName="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server"  GroupName="Group1" AutoPostBack="True"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server"  GroupName="Group1" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButton1.Checked)
                TextBox3.Enabled = false;
            else
                TextBox3.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Again... Yeah, that is a solution for this very problem, but for the future I have to know how to force the changes I make in the code behind on any of the controls. So e.g. I want to disable a textbox on a radiobutton selection event. How to do that?

Comment: you can see that in my example , when you select radiobutton1 it will disable Textbox1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of both radiobuttons the same, so the Code Behind you wrote is not needed anymore.

Also, check out the [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Your aspx-code should look something like this:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButtonEnabled" runat="server" Text="Enabled" GroupName="GroupTxtEnabled" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonEnabled_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:RadioButton id="RadioButtonDisabled" runat="server" Text="Disabled"  GroupName="GroupTxtEnabled" AutoPostBack="True"/>

<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
```

And in your code-behind:

```
protected void RadioButtonEnabled_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1 = RadioButtonEnabled.Checked
}
```

As you can see, I've used the `OnCheckedChanged` only at one radiobutton, since both radiobuttons are changed at the same time (property `GroupName` is equal).

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution for this very problem, but for the future I have to know how to force the changes I make in the code behind on any of the controls. So e.g. I want to disable a textbox on a radiobutton selection event. How to do that?

Comment: Are you sure your event is wired up correctly in your ASPX-page?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Put the checkboxes in a GroubBox or Panel